# ActiveMQ XStream ForbiddenClassException

Tags: activemq-classic, xstream

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.16.2 as broker and client 5.16.1 in my java app. Sometimes I get this error in a loop:

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException
cause-message       : java.io.IOException
class               : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
required-type       : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
converter-type      : 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse/exception
line number         : 5
version             : 1.4.15
-------------------------------
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:34)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.run(HttpClientTransport.java:205)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException
cause-message       : java.io.IOException
class               : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
required-type       : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse/exception
line number         : 5
version             : 1.4.15
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1409)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1388)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1273)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1264)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.xstream.XStreamWireFormat.unmarshalText(XStreamWireFormat.java:66)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.util.TextWireFormat.unmarshal(TextWireFormat.java:56)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.run(HttpClientTransport.java:196)
... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: java.io.IOException
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.NoTypePermission.allows(NoTypePermission.java:26)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:74)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:420)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:277)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
... 13 common frames omitted
```

I already have a similar error this XStream when I'm in 5.16.0 and correct in 5.16.1, but now it's another one.

I tried using the 5.16.2 client, but I get the same error:

```
--- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : 
com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException
cause-message       : java.io.IOException
class               : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
required-type       : org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse/exception
line number         : 5
version             : 1.4.16
-------------------------------
```

The exception occurs on the client. We are using XStream because the client is connecting via HTTP and XStream is required on the client for this use-case according to [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/http-and-https-transports-reference.html).

This application has been running in TCP for a very long time, but we have to use it also in HTTPS. Since we've been testing HTTPS we have had some weird behavior with tests that fail due to XStream errors, but other HTTPS calls work without problem. I'm just trying to figure out why switching to HTTPS is causing this.

Comment: i don't include xstream in my maven dependancy, it's include by activemq that try (i think) to read the data and give me this exception...

Comment: we just download the activemq broker tarball on official site and unzip it, and effectively, i see xstream (with many other) in lib/optional...i don't have it in lib directory

Comment: we have this problematic because we have to connect to activemq in http not in tcp

Comment: @JustinBertram on the client, so i don't have to move jar from optional to lib i think

Comment: it's not my app directly because i help colleague on this problem, i just know that we use camel in this application, perhaps it's him that use xstream implicitely.. i check

Comment: We jave to add activemq-http as maven dependancy because as i said before, we connect to activemq with http protocol because not possible to use tcp in this case, so i can t remove this dependancy

Comment: Just recently because before we use tcp and now for some reasons we need to have this application working in https so we test this case. and for some others reasons sometime all working good message are correctly distribued to queue or topic. We can observe many loose connection and automatic reconnection after.

Comment: sorry i will try to clarify, this application has been running in tcp for a very long time and we have to use it also in https and since we are testing https, we have some weird behavior with tests that fail due to xstream error and other https call that works without problem. I'm just trying to figure out why switching to https is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like XStream is trying to deal with an OpenWire `org.apache.activemq.command.ExceptionResponse` message which is coming from the broker. This message contains a serialized `java.io.IOException` and XStream fails to convert this as it is expecting an XML payload instead. That's why the exception says:

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: java.io.IOException
```

The `ForbiddenClassException` is the exception which XStream throws in response to the `java.io.IOException` which it can't convert.

It's not clear what is triggering the `java.io.IOException` in the first place so that would be worth investigating (e.g. look at the broker logs). The XStream failure itself appears to be a bug. However, I'm not sure how well-maintained the HTTP/S transport is so a bug-fix may not be available soon (if ever). You might try migrating from ActiveMQ 5.x (i.e. "Classic") to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/) which also [supports HTTP/S](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html#configuring-netty-http).

Comment: ok i will try to search again and i will get back to you if i find something. Thanks for help